# ObtainAuthToken post function customization. How to get token and name in the response?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I´m trying to get response that include name apart from token.
In the documentation https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/ about **ObtainAuthToken** I see we can overwrite the post fn but I´m not sure how to apply it in my CreateTokenView class.

serializers.py

```
class AuthTokenSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """Serializer for the user authentication object"""
    email = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField(
        style={'input_type': 'password'},
        trim_whitespace=False
    )

    def validate(self,attrs):
        """Overwriting the validate() fn"""
        email = attrs.get('email')
        password = attrs.get('password')

        user = authenticate(
            request=self.context.get('request'),
            username=email,
            password=password
        )
        if not user:
            msg = _('Unable to authenticate with provided credentials')
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code='authentication')

        attrs['user'] = user
        return attrs
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken

class CreateTokenView(ObtainAuthToken):
    """Create a new auth token for user"""
    serializer_class = AuthTokenSerializer
    renderer_classes = api_settings.DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES
```

Comment: " but I´m not sure how to apply it in my CreateTokenView class."

what do you mean? You have to do the same

Comment: Ok, it was just add the code from docs and customize the Response  kwargs. thx

Answer (score 0):

Add the post fn and customize the kwargs

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.response import Response

class CreateTokenView(ObtainAuthToken):
    """Create a new auth token for user"""
    serializer_class = AuthTokenSerializer
    renderer_classes = api_settings.DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data,
                                        context={'request': request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response({
            'token': token.key,
            'name': user.name
        })
```